# Create additionals vhost/user/pass for RabbitMQ at helm chart for Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

Edit: I need to set some additionals rabbit vhost/users/pass at helm charts for a rabbitMQ we use in K8s, I tried via curl in a lifecyle postStart hook:

Here's an example:

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["'/bin/sh', '-c','curl -i -u guest:guest -H ''content-type:application/json'' -XPUT -d '''{'password':'1234','tags':'monitoring'}''' http://localhost:15672/api/users/deleteme'"]
```

But fails :

```
Killing container with id docker://rabbitmq:FailedPostStartHook
```

I tried changing quotation and also setting it like:

```
command:
 - "sh":
 - "-c":
 - etc....
```

With no success, it's the first time I'm using hooks, any advice, please?
Thanks!

full statefulset:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
spec:
  serviceName: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  updateStrategy:
    type: {{ .Values.updateStrategy }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: epmd
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 4369
            - name: amqp
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 5672
            - name: http
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 15672
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - rabbitmqctl
                - status
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - rabbitmqctl
                - status
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          env:
            - name: MY_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME
              value: "true"
            - name: RABBITMQ_NODENAME
              value: "rabbit@$(MY_POD_IP)"
            - name: K8S_SERVICE_NAME
              value: {{ .Chart.Name }}
            - name: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
                  key: rabbitmq-erlang-cookie
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
              value: {{ .Values.rabbitmqUsername | quote }}
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
                  key: rabbitmq-password
            - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST
              value: {{ .Values.rabbitmqVhost | quote }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq
          lifecycle:
              postStart:
                exec:
                  command:
                  - "sh"
                  - "-c"
                  - "curl -i -u guest:guest -H \"content-type:application/json\" -XPUT -d \"{\"password\":\"1234\",\"tags\":\"monitoring\"}\" http://rabbitmq:15672/api/users/deleteme"
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 1
              podAffinityTerm:
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
```

I might ending up using values or trying to set it up at configmap:
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha

If there's a better way, would be great.

Comment: You've mentioned PostStart in the first sentence and PreStop in the example. It looks like a mistake.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I modified at the actual yaml, I'm using postStart.

Comment: It seems that command in PostStart hook returns non zero value. Is that command necessary to run the container? If not, try to remove PostStart hook from the spec, start the pod, exec shell into the pod and run that command manually to ensure that it can run successfully.

Comment: Actually, that's how we do it right now, and I want to avoid running these curls manually from time to time when we have a new rabbit.

Comment: Could you provide full deployment spec? I guess that command runs before the service becomes ready. Perhaps some initial pause can fix the problem.

Comment: Added at my first comment. I'm thinking of using values.yaml or the configmap: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha
Thanks!

Comment: Changed the title and description, the main goal it's to add more vhost/user/pass, either via curl or at helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to look at Helm [Hooks](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_hooks.md). They consist with various options to interpose at certain phases of the development life cycle. Hooks represent themselves as regular templates, however they require a special annotations to be set in order Helm to interpret them correctly.

```
apiVersion: ...
kind: ....
metadata:
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
# ...
```

You can consider to run a Job with `post-install` hook which executes after all resources are loaded into Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give a try. Hope to make the curl work at command: thought...It's a bit tricky. At least it failed when I tried at postStart statefulset hook.